# Azure AD B2C Single Logout implementation

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have 2 web aplications using AAD B2C single sign-on, the Mainsite.mydomain.com and support.provider.com (note that they are in different domains). My B2C has only local users, so no external IdP (e.g. Google, Facebooks, etc).

Single sign-on works as expected and the individual logout from each website works as expected.

Now I want Single Logout, i.e. when the users logout from the Mainsite I want them to be automatically logged out from the Support website, too. At logout from each app I do call the OIDC /logout endpoint to kill the B2C session as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request), but that isn't enough to logout from the other application.

Reading the OIDC specs it seems there are 3 ways to have single-logoff, as described [here](https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/openid-connect-logout-eccc73df758f), but none of them seem to be available for B2C:

- Front-end channel (it would require registering a Logout URL for each
  app, but B2C apps don't have this attribute)
- Back-end channel (it would require registering a Logout URL for each
  app, but B2C apps don't have this attribute)
- Session Management (this requires a check_session_iframe URL, which
  is not provided by the B2C /.well-known endpoint)

So it seems that none of the standard methods are supported by B2C, did anybody manage to figure out  how to do it?

**Note**: There's another similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187094/azure-ad-b2c-sign-out-a-user-from-all-sessions) but the single response doesn't actually answer the question and the comments to it show that others couldn't do single logoff either. Even more, my case is even simpler as I don't have any external IdP.

Comment: Did you register the Logout URL on both B2C applications, on Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes, I did, but that's for AAD. Did you manage to successfully have Single Logout on AAD B2C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft Support, this is currently not possible. They even pointed me to a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19211881-single-sign-out-in-b2c) for this exact thing, but it's not on their near-term roadmap.